# Canvas rectangle image

Tags: javascript, canvas

So i started to work with canvas and I had a problem to get used to layers and their fills.

After several hours I managed to make simple animations using basic colors but the main problem is when i want to fill boxes array

```
var boxes = [];
boxes.push({
    x: 50,
    y: 200,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});
```

containing coordinates and parameters with pattern.

```
var pat = ctx.createPattern(ground_block_200_80,'repeat');
```

to make a rectangle from boxes array I use

```
    ctx.fillStyle = pat;
    ctx.fillRect(boxes[0].x, boxes[0].y, boxes[0].width, boxes[0].height);
```

it fills whole layer starting from X = 0 and Y = 0 but I would like to start patern from top left corner of rectangle

Is it possible to somehow move layer or adjust pattern?

Comment: There are no layers in Context2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box there's no widespread way to adjust the pattern to a specific offset. There's a [`setTransform` method defined in the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-canvaspattern-settransform) but support is [very scarce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern/setTransform#Browser_compatibility).

Your best choice is probably not to use a pattern and rely on `drawImage()` instead.

***Note:*** you could combine using a pattern in the "top-left" region of your rect, and use `drawImage` around the bottom & right borders for efficiency if the pattern is repeated many times inside each box, but it will be a complex, error prone code.

Comment: Thanks for advice ill try drawIMage then. Is it demanding to performance?, should i avoid rendering it too much?

Comment: That depends on your scenario. Any "work" is less performant than no work - run your code and if it's too slow, profile it